# Update cached data for multiple queries that are related on single mutation in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have following queries with in my codebase :

1. Query all the articles

```
useInfiniteQuery(
    ['articles', { pageSize: props.pageSize }],
    queryFn
  );
```

2. Query articles of an single category

```
useInfiniteQuery(
    ['articles', { categoryId : props.categoryId , pageSize: props.pageSize }],
    queryFn
  );
```

3. Query articles related to single a user

```
useInfiniteQuery(
    ['articles', { username : props.username , pageSize: props.pageSize }],
    queryFn
  );
```

and for every article there is 'Like' feature so i have created a mutation for it.

```
useMutation(
    articleApi.likePost(props),
    {
      onMutate: () => {
       // I want to implement cache update here
       // is there any way to update the liked article 
       // from all 3 queries at the same time if it present in all of 
       // them or some of them
      },     
    }
  );
```

My question is is there any way to update the liked article onMutate from all 3 queries at the same time if it present in all of them or some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [setQueriesData](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetqueriesdata)

It will call `setQueryData` for all matching queries, and you can use fuzzy matching to find your entries. Especially if all 3 entries have the same structure, you can do:

`queryClient.setQueriesData(['articles'], newData)`

to update them all